# Connected mongodb with power bi with ODBC Driver

Tags: mongodb, powerbi, odbc

Can you guide me about the connection between mongodb and power bi through ODBC driver. I have connection between them. but i got unexpected errors like:

> "OLE DB or ODBC error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E4E."  , "OLE DB
> or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] ODBC: ERROR [42S22] [MySQL][ODBC
> 1.4(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.12 mongosqld v2.14.3]Unknown column 'COD' in 'field list'."

and

> "DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [08S01] [MYSQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver Lost
> conection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication
> packet', system error: 10060".

Can you tell me where the problem and how can I overcome on it?

Comment: Do you have a local MongoDB running?

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit I don't and I have the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem, try to go over the below steps and take a look at my advice under the fourth point (4).

1. Install mongosqld on your server based on your OS ([first prerequisites](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/current/tutorial/create-system-dsn/)).
2. LunchBI connector:

   a) Make **logs** folder and mongosqld.log file in it.
   b) Setup mongosqld.conf (**IP**:<your_server_ip>, **PORT**:3307)
3. Install mongosqld as a System Service [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/current/launch/#install-mongosqld-as-a-system-service)
4. Create a system DSN on your computer based on your OS, [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/current/tutorial/create-system-dsn/).

   **Hint**: On Windows (in ODBC data source) try to make both ANSI and UNICODE
   connectors and do not forget to select a database in the **dropdown menu**.*
5. e.g. connect to Mongo via PowerBI via ODBC

   a) Select a connector

   b) Select the database, that you have selected in the previous dropdown menu.

For more information follow the official [guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/current/)

Answer (score 0):

you have to install mongosqld on your server and configure the .yalm file.
Inside it you have to uptade 'bind ip' field, by adding the remote ip.